# React navigation native collapsible header

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm studying React Native. With react navigation, I create a navigation stack. At the top of the emulator screen, I see the title bar. Now I want to revive it. I found in the document navigation section of this page

https://github.com/benevbright/react-navigation-collapsible

But all the examples in this project are written in TypeScript files, and I use JavaScript.
Maybe I can find a JavaScript example somewhere on how to use react-navigation-collapsible.

Comment: I went to the link you gave and the examples are all given in js. TS and JS not too much difference, if you spend time looking at it, you will know how to type in JS.